# Why does my Android app looks different from english to spanish?

Tags: android

I have written an Android app. It has both English and spanish strings.xml files. When Android is in English the app looks exactly as it is intended, but when Android is in spanish it looks diferent. I don't mean the texts, I mean things like text boxes and buttons and things like that.

Whay does this happen? How do I get it to look the same in all languages?

I can't post images rigth now because I'm new in Stackoverflow and need more reputation, but I posted a couple of screenshots on a web server; these are the URLs:

In spanish: http://s24.postimg.org/h2w32w7k5/Screenshot_01_esp.png

In English: http://s27.postimg.org/phoedk2rn/Screenshot_01_eng.png

Comment: Obvious question, but - same device both times, right?

Comment: Yes stkent, same device both times. I have tested in several other devices and the same thing happens.

Comment: Are you using language qualifiers anywhere other than in the `strings.xml` file? Is it a Nexus device?

Comment: Not any language qualifiers. I've tested it on Samsung Galaxy S2, S3, S4, S5, Motorola Atrix, Motorola X, Motorola G, Sony Xperia Z1 and others. The same thing happens.

Comment: What happens if you swap to a different language, like French or German? Which appearance do you see?

Comment: Do you have a `res/values-es/styles.xml`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everybody for your interest. I've found the reason: There are other styles.xml files in other folders of the project, these folders are named: res/values-vXX.

These style files are used acording to the API where the app is executed. The hint to find this is on the very original styles.xml file:

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
```

So what I did was to use the same parent style in all the styles.xml files.

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you use different styles for those localizations.

Assert `res/values/styles.xml` and `res/values-es/styles.xml` are using identical activity style.

Comment: Both styles files are exactly the same.

Comment: please use `traceview` from SDK tools to assure it. Looks as different styles are used.